# My React Web App works fine in local host but doesn't work when hosted

Tags: reactjs

My React web app works when ran locally but when deployed online on 2 different sites it doesn't display even though the view-source had all the code. Can anyone help me with this problem.

Hosting on 2 different sites.

Comment: It would help if you would press F12 and check if there are any errors, without that it's just guessing.

Comment: The script from “https://brettoconnordesigns.firebaseapp.com/:caretakerx/brettoconnordesigns.git/static/js/2.50f572c3.chunk.js” was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.
work

Comment: The stylesheet https://brettoconnordesigns.firebaseapp.com/:caretakerx/brettoconnordesigns.git/static/css/main.f0f18f1e.chunk.css was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”. work
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
2.50f572c3.chunk.js:1
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
main.1eae08cb.chunk.js:1

​

Comment: The url is https://brettoconnordesigns.firebaseapp.com/

Comment: CSS, js, ico and json all return html I guess it's something with your web server. Maybe every url returns the homepage; including urls to resources.

Comment: I noticed that running npm start runs the app but running the index file from the folder doesn't. Anyone have a solution.